# Phonegap Cordova file move issues

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have look threw most of the post and found the below code which I have modified to fit my needs. But I can't seem to get it to return the full new path of the file. and the file is not moved?

```
function successCallback(entry) {



    alert("Success. New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error.code)
    alert(error.code);
}


function moveFile(fileUri) {

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          fileUri,
          function(fileEntry){
                newFileUri  = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "images/";
                oldFileUri  = fileUri;
                fileExt     = "." + oldFileUri.split('.').pop();
                newFileName = uniqueId() + fileExt;

                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newFileUri ,
                        function(dirEntry) {
                            // move the file to a new directory and rename it
                    alert(dirEntry.fullPath)
                            fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, newFileName, successCallback, errorCallback);
                        },
                        errorCallback);
          },
          errorCallback);
}
```

now the **successCallback** gets called but the new file path is wrong, and the file is not moved.

Comment: Mike, I am experiencing the exact same thing. dirEntry.fullPath = "/" which is NOT correct and so though it calls Success function it does in fact NOT move the file. What did you determine to be the issue? Thx.

Comment: Ric@ I will get you the code tonight once I get home ( at work right now) if you still need it let me know

Comment: Mike@ I DO need it!  I appreciate your getting back. Let me know if you need an email.

Comment: Ric@ see my answer below I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

```
function moveFile(fileUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileUri, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function successCallback(entry) {

    var newFileName = uniqueId() + '.jpg';

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (fileSys) {
            fileSys.root.getDirectory("reunion", {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                },
                function (directory) {
                    window.rootFS = fileSys.root;
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, FileMoved, errorCallback);
                }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
}


function FileMoved(entry) {

     var image = window.rootFS.toURL() + entry.fullPath;
     var d = new Date();

    var html = '<img class="imgPost" data-count="' + window.ImageCount + '" id="img' + window.ImageCount + '" width="100%" src="' + image + '?' + d.getTime() + '" />';
    html += '<a id="deleteImgBnt' + window.ImageCount + '" href="#" data-count="' + window.ImageCount + '" class="deletephoto ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-d" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right"> Delete Image </a> ';

    $('#photo').prepend(html);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error.code)
    alert(error.code);
}

function uniqueId() {
    // desired length of Id
    var idStrLen = 32;
    // always start with a letter -- base 36 makes for a nice shortcut
    var idStr = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 25)) + 10).toString(36) + "_";
    // add a timestamp in milliseconds (base 36 again) as the base
    idStr += (new Date()).getTime().toString(36) + "_";
    // similar to above, complete the Id using random, alphanumeric characters
    do {
        idStr += (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35))).toString(36);
    } while (idStr.length < idStrLen);

    return (idStr);
}
function moveFile(fileUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileUri, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function successCallback(entry) {

    var newFileName = uniqueId() + '.jpg';

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (fileSys) {
            fileSys.root.getDirectory("reunion", {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                },
                function (directory) {
                    window.rootFS = fileSys.root;
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, FileMoved, errorCallback);
                }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
}


function FileMoved(entry) {

     var image = window.rootFS.toURL() + entry.fullPath;
     var d = new Date();

    var html = '<img class="imgPost" data-count="' + window.ImageCount + '" id="img' + window.ImageCount + '" width="100%" src="' + image + '?' + d.getTime() + '" />';
    html += '<a id="deleteImgBnt' + window.ImageCount + '" href="#" data-count="' + window.ImageCount + '" class="deletephoto ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-d" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right"> Delete Image </a> ';

    $('#photo').prepend(html);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error.code)
    alert(error.code);
}

function uniqueId() {
    // desired length of Id
    var idStrLen = 32;
    // always start with a letter -- base 36 makes for a nice shortcut
    var idStr = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 25)) + 10).toString(36) + "_";
    // add a timestamp in milliseconds (base 36 again) as the base
    idStr += (new Date()).getTime().toString(36) + "_";
    // similar to above, complete the Id using random, alphanumeric characters
    do {
        idStr += (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35))).toString(36);
    } while (idStr.length < idStrLen);

    return (idStr);
}
```

Comment: Mike@ I wanted to add a bit to what I got from your code that might help too. Where you use 'image = window.rootFS.toURL() + entry.fullPath' you get something like 'file:///var/mobile/Applications/<application UUID>/Documents//reunion/YourFile'  Notice the // before 'reunion'. it seems to work but it is weird.  I found that if you simply code 'image = entry.toURL()' you got the same dir you wanted but without the //, but a single slash.

Comment: Thanks ric i check that out

Comment: Mike@ my experience with this code showed that yes, I could use this 'image' reference to display the image on my html page. However, ONLY while the app was running in that instance. If I killed the app and started again, that image reference was no good, even if I had stored it in localStorage. What I found was if instead of the change I suggested I coded 'image = entry.toInternalURL()' Image was a translated to a cdvfile reference, as in 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/reunion/YourFile'. When I saved THAT in localStorage I could use it to successfully load the image into a page on mynext run

Comment: Yes, in the final: 'image = entry.toInternalURL()' was persistent across app runs. Note the word internal is capital I, as in Internal. I'll try to find the quote in the File docs.

Comment: In the Cordova-plugin-File docs:  "In v1.1.0 the return value of toURL() was changed (see CB-6394) to return an absolute 'file://' URL. wherever possible. To ensure a 'cdvfile:'-URL you can use toInternalURL() now. This method will now return filesystem URLs of the form"  Read up on that function.

Comment: I appreciate your going back into your code for me. With that as a guide I was able to get out of the woods. If you want my whole working code to save an image file I will be glad to email it to you.